# --go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1

Tags: go, grpc, proto, protoc

i am getting this error when i compile my proto file:

```
protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
\--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I am using these versions:

| Binary | Version |
| --- | --- |
| protoc-gen-go | v1.25.0-devel |
| protoc | v3.12.4 |

I have tried to compile this proto file:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "proto/";

message GreetingRequest {
  string first_name = 1;
  string last_name = 2;
}
message GreetingResponse{
  string result = 1;
}

service AddService{
  rpc Greet(GreetingRequest) returns (GreetingResponse) {};
}
```

I used this command:

```sh
protoc \
--proto_path=proto \
--go_out=proto \
--go_opt=paths=source_relative \
--go-grpc_out=proto \
--go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
service.proto
```

I installed `protoc-gen-go-grpc` using:

```sh
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

but its still showing this error.

Comment: Thank you for the clear repro of your issue. Are you running on Linux? If so, please try `which protoc-gen-go-grpc` to determine where (in your path), the binary can be found. I suspect, it won't be found and you'll need to add it's location to your `PATH`

Comment: For me, the file is in `${GOPATH}/bin`. You may not have `GOPATH` (and I think there's a `GOBIN`) too.

Comment: When you run `protoc`, it looks for plugins (other binaries) in the `PATH` on your system. In your case, there are 2 plugins that are used. `--go_*` is matched to a binary `protoc-gen-go` and `--go-grpc_*` is matched to a binary `protoc-gen-go-grpc`. The flags are used to determine the binary's name `protoc-gen-[[FLAG]]`. You just need to ensure that both those binaries are in the `PATH` so that `protoc` can find them when you run it.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Right after installing protoc-gen-go-grpc I have used following command to set path:   **export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"**
  which sets the path to: **/home/zohaib/go/bin/protoc-gen-go-grpc**     
  but the path should be:   **/usr/bin** 
where protoc-gen-go lies.

Comment: I'm unsure whether your comment was a statement of a question. To reiterate, you need to set the `PATH` to include whatever paths you're using so that `protoc` can find `protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-go-gprc` in the `PATH`. If these are in different locations **both** folders need to be in the `PATH`.

Comment: Found a temporary solution to the problem, everytime before compiling my proto file I have to explicitly set path of `protoc-gen-go-grpc` in the terminal using: `PATH="/myDirectory:$PATH"`. _Now the problem is how to set this path permanently?_

Answer (score 2):

Hello if you are running on mac m1 try using this command

export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"

to make this change permanent you may have to modify your ~/.zshrc file and source it

got it from here

https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/

Comment: This actually was my issue, thanks for that.